# Arduino, Firefly, Servo not communicating

Tags: arduino, grasshopper

I am trying to control 2 servos using firefly. I had it working [(proof)](http://variabledimensions.tumblr.com/post/33803960587/aint-no-stoppin-so-this-evening-and-after-hours) and now it doesn't seem to work...

my setup is as follows:
- Arduino Mega 2560 R3
- Arduino sensor Shield V5.0
- 2 standard servos (plugged into pins 9 and 10 in the sensor shield)
- 7.5V wall power supply
- USB cable to computer

I'm running Rhino SR 8 on a 32 bit Windows Vista machine
I have Version 0.9.0014 of grasshopper (the latest) and Firefly_Build_1.0067 (also the latest)
I have flashed my Arduino board with the latest firefly firmata (updated September 10th, 2012)

I have checked that I am using the "MEGA write" box
I have got the right bits going to the right pins and I have checked that they all have "servo" ticked instead of "digital" or "pwm"

My servos and board work perfectly well with the normal Arduino software, but just not any longer with firefly.

The port shows correctly as COM 4 and opens fine in firefly.

When I move the slider to control the servos, the TX light is on and the RX light flashes, but no servos move...

(to confirm: everything works with the sweep example in arduino, so I have eliminated power and wiring issues)...

Any ideas what might be the problem?

I've tried re-installing, switching off and on many times, changing cables, trying a different board (also doesn't work any more with the duemilanove), trying all pins on the shield, trying one servo without the shield, trying one servo with the shield, lots of googling, lots of searching forums, unblocking the firefly installation files in explorer, lots of things... I'm all out of ideas... And very confused as it was working just a few days ago... Am I just missing something really obvious or could there be an issue with the software at my end?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect a resistor and LED to the signal port of the servo's, that way you can see if the servo's actually receive the signal or not.